# How do I get the Realtek RT8139 ethernet port working on a Dell Inspiron N5010?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet, realtek

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 onto my Dell Inspiron N5010 and Ive been all over many forums trying to figure out how I can get my ethernet cable to be recognized so I can set up a wired connection.

My Network Card is the Realtek RT8139 and from what Ive gathered the ethernet port driver for it is installed.  Whenever I run ifconfig in the terminal it says that eth1 is up and running but no matter how I edit the connection I cannot get it to work.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running on battery or AC?

Answer (score 1):

Just curious if you are running on Battery power or AC Power?

I recently upgraded my Toughbook from 12.04 to 12.10 and was pulling my hair out as my Wireless was working but my Wired connection would not connect.  Once I plugged in my AC Adapter it turned on and connected showing me it was a Power Management setting preventing it from working before.

Thought this might be helpful to you.